# How to query my JSON file for specific key

Tags: json, github-actions

I am working on a project where I want to query a JSon using Jquery but I am getting an error:

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected IDENT, expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
..id  
jq: 1 compile error
Error: Process completed with exit code 3.
```

I am using the command:

```
jq '..id' new_file.json
```

To query my JSON file which is named new_file.json

Here is my JSON file:

```
[
  {
    "type": "users_export",
    "status": "pending",
    "connection_id": "con_kmZIjREZWYzt39JI",
    "format": "json",
    "limit": 5,
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "user_id"
      },
      {
        "name": "user_id",
        "export_as": "provider"
      },
      {
        "name": "username"
      },
      {
        "name": "username",
        "export_as": "provider"
      },
      {
        "name": "nickname"
      },
      {
        "name": "email"
      },
      {
        "name": "email"
      },
      {
        "name": "identities[0].connection",
        "export_as": "provider"
      },
      {
        "name": "email_verified",
        "export_as": "provider"
      }
    ],
    "connection": "dev-default-evoyanbs",
    "created_at": "2022-11-16T17:45:58.429Z",
    "id": "job_aztDgKXWT8g8iZ5T"
  }
]
```

I want the '`job_aztDgKXWT8g8iZ5T`' as my output but I am getting the above mentioned error, can someone please help me out, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have an array, the command should be:

```
jq '.[].id' new_file.json
```

And the result will be: `"job_aztDgKXWT8g8iZ5T"`.

If you want to get rid of double quotes in your output, you can add **raw-output** flag in your command, like this:

```
jq -r '.[].id' new_file.json
```

or

```
jq --raw-output '.[].id' new_file.json
```

Comment: Is there any way we can get rid of the inverted commas we are getting as a result?

Comment: @learner, I have just updated the post. Is it ok for you?